# Regex, substring htmlstring

Tags: c#

I have a html string to be parsed.
    ResultsString

```
         <table id="Table1">
            <tr>
              <td width="50%">
                 Result: <span style="font-weight:bold; color:GREEN;"></span>
               </td>
               <td width="50%">
                  ID: <span style="font-weight:bold;">790043</span>
               </td>
           </table>
         <table id="Table2">
            <tr>
              <td class="name">
                Status:
             </td>
             <td class="value">
                None
             </td>
             </tr>

        </table>
<br /><br />
<a href="#" onclick="$('#vvvv').toggle();return false;" /></a>
<br />
<div id="pp1" style="displa
</div>
```

How would I extract/substring only the text in the two table tags. 
So my resuting html string would be

```
   <table id="Table1">
            <tr>
              <td width="50%">
                 Result: <span style="font-weight:bold; color:GREEN;"></span>
               </td>
               <td width="50%">
                  ID: <span style="font-weight:bold;">790043</span>
               </td>
           </table>
         <table id="Table2">
            <tr>
              <td class="name">
                Status:
             </td>
             <td class="value">
                None
             </td>
             </tr>

        </table>
```

Please suggest

Thank u

Comment: Forget Regex and use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: [Do not use regex with html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/580951). Use a html parser instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you should use an HTML parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Otherwise, you may run into problems if you have nested structures, etc.

For this simple case though, you can use this regular expression:

```
string html = Regex.Match(ResultsString,
                          @"<table.+<\/table>",
                          RegexOptions.Singleline).Value;
```

But again, only if your input string is as simple as you showed us!

Comment: Please do not tell beginners to use Regex to parse HTML; it is never appropriate. If the HTML truly is as simple as claimed, then `String.Substring` is adequate. If this is not adequate, then neither is a Regex.

Comment: a) I do explicitly recommend to use a parser instead. b) so when it really is that simple, `Substring` is ok and `Regex` is not? Give me a break

Answer (score 0):

You want to transform an HTML file? That's an [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) job.